# Order of middle group in short exact sequence

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

If we have a short exacts sequence of abelian group with $A$ and $C$ finite, $0\to A\to B\to C$, is it true that $|B|=|A|\cdot |C|$ even if it does not split?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's simply Lagrange's theorem. By definition of short exact sequence, $C\cong B/\operatorname{im}(f)$, where $f\colon A\to B$ is the given map. Since $f$ is injective, $\lvert\operatorname{im}(f)\rvert=|A|$.